# PyGTK, "do-configure-event" doesn't work?

Tags: pygtk

The title of the window doesn't display event.x && event.y (see the code :D) .

I discover the method do_configure_event doesn't been called.

new to pygtk,
many thx! :D

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
# encoding:utf8
# sources: zetcode
import gtk
import gobject

class pyapp:
    __gsignals__ = {
        "configure-event" : "override"
    }
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        self.window.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
        self.window.set_size_request(350,200)
        self.window.show_all()

    def do_configure_event(self, event):
        title = "%s, %s" % ( event.x, event,y)
        self.window.set_title(title)
        gtk.Window.do_configure_event(self, event)

pyapp()
gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Name your sources!* It seems you're trying to adapt example code from [Zetcode](http://zetcode.com/gui/pygtk/signals/) you do not fully comprehend.
Your problem is: to put your class attribute `__gsignals__` into use, you have to derive from `gtk.Window`. The window instance looks up the signals and therefore its gsignals dictionary has to be filled. At the moment, this dictionary resides in `pyapp`.